Accessing window.location.origin in Next.js 14 server component
How can I access the window.location.origin in Next.js 14 from a server component? The popular answer provided here for Next.js 13 doesn't work.

Could you add more context and what actually you've tried from the provided answer? I don't know  headers from next but doesn't seem related.

You can replicate the window.location.origin value in next.js 14 with the x-forwarded-host and x-forwarded-proto headers, see: Functions: headers | Next.js
const headersList = headers();
const host = headersList.get('X-Forwarded-Host');
const proto = headersList.get('X-Forwarded-Proto');


what I would suggest to try is tu use getServerSideProps here on the docs. I haven't try but i think it could possibly work.
import type { InferGetServerSidePropsType, GetServerSideProps } from 'next'
 

 
export const getServerSideProps = (async () => {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const origin = window.location.origin
  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { origin } }
}) 
 
export default function Page({
  repo,
}: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>) {
  return (
    <main>
      <p>{origin}</p>
    </main>
  )
}

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

This may work but appears to me like using a Next.13 pattern (Pages Router) when I want to do things the Next.14 way. What do you think? @theo

This will objectively not work. getServerSideProps runs on the server.

This is from my own app. Obviously you'll need to modify it to fit your needs, but you now have to set the header yourself.
export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const requestHeaders = new Headers(req.headers);
    let host = req.nextUrl.host
    if (!req.url.startsWith("/api")) {
        const _locationHeader = req.url.includes(host) ? req.url.split(host)[1] : req.url
        requestHeaders.set('x-url', _locationHeader);
    }
    return NextResponse.next({
        request: {
            headers: requestHeaders,
        }
    });
}

And then you can get it in a server component at the x-url header.
Oops. I misunderstood the question. This will return the pathname on the server, if anyone is looking to accomplish that.
To get the root, use process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL. You'll need to set it yourself if you're running it locally, but on vercel it's automatically populated with the host url.

something like this could work but I am looking to replicate the value of window.location.origin and I don't know that host is an equivalent value. The origin has the http/https:// substring included

I've read your update, but I won't be using vercel and I won't be using next-auth

The nextauth_url is populated regardless of whether or not you're using next auth, but I don't know if it will be populated if you're deploying on another platform. Just set an env variable yourself.

I appreciate your answer but in my case I'd like it to be dynamic, this is for a redirectUri in auth0 so when in local env i want it to redirect to local host and respond to various dev and prod urls aswell
